# How to implement gRPC in a .NET Core 2.1 application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc

I am working on a .NET core docker based application, i am unable to find a good documentation to understand how to implement gRPC, the gRPC documentation is bit outdated, Does anyone know any documentation that is up to date?

Comment: https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/csharp.html

Comment: @Arash this one is bit outdated

Comment: how about to watch pluralsight course : https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/grpc-enhancing-application-communication

Answer (score 0):

To understand gRPC in .net core, the [quick start article of official website](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/csharp.html) is enough.
Aware that since gRPC tools 1.17 released, there is a new, easier and simpler way to generate .cs message files. You can reference [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/BUILD-INTEGRATION.md).